# filtering observable array from drop down menu in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I only started learning about and using knockout.js a few days ago.  I have been working through the interactive tutorials on thier website and other related beginner excercises and have formed a basic understanding.

I am trying to create a 'log handler' application that will basically display some hardcoded error logs with log ID, description and date logged.

I have a dropdown select menu with three filtering options but I am really struggling with getting the filtering to work.  For example filtering the ID to only display the logs with ID between 0 to 5000.  I have tried various methods including the code shown below where I attempt to itirate through the array elements, clearing that array, and then populating that array with elements that match the `if` conditions, and finally displaying that array.  However I am unsure where to display the filtered array as it will overwrite the original array `self.logs`.

**View**

```
<span style="margin-left:40px">Filter <select data-bind="options: filters,optionsText : 'name', selectedOptions: chosenFilter, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select></span>
<span style="margin-left:20px"><button data-bind="enable: chosenFilter, click: resetFilter">Reset filter</button></span>
<table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 25px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Log ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date logged</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: logs">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: errorDetails().description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: errorDetails().date"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeLog">Remove log</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**ViewModel**

```
// Overall
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        // Class to represent details of individual logs
        function logDetails(id, errorDescription) {
            var self = this;
            self.id = id;
            self.errorDetails = ko.observable(errorDescription);
        };

        self.filters = [
            { name: "Log ID (0-5000)" },
            { name: "Log description (A-Z)" },
            { name: "Date logged (most recent first)" }],
            self.chosenFilter = ko.observable(),
            self.resetFilter = function () { self.chosenFilter(null) },


            // Non-editable data - would come from the server
            self.descriptions = [
                { description: "Error binding data", date: "08/07/2018" },
                { description: "Error requesting data", date: "09/07/2018" },
                { description: "Error submitting request", date: "05/07/2018" },
                { description: "Warning - User does not have have priviliges", date: "04/05/2018" },
                { description: "New Error", date: "xx/xx/xxxx" }
            ],


            // Editable data
            self.logs = ko.observableArray([
                new logDetails(0035, self.descriptions[0]),
                new logDetails(1468, self.descriptions[1]),
                new logDetails(9021, self.descriptions[2]),
                new logDetails(9021, self.descriptions[2]),
                new logDetails(4068, self.descriptions[3]),
                new logDetails(4068, self.descriptions[3]),
                new logDetails(1468, self.descriptions[1])
            ]),

            // Operations
            self.addLog = function () {
                self.logs.push(new logDetails("xxxx", self.descriptions[4]));
            },
            self.removeLog = function (log) { self.logs.remove(log) }

        filteredLogs: ko.observablearray([]),
           find0to5000: function() {
                var counter = filteredLogs().length;
                for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                    filteredLogs().pop();
                }

                ko.utils.arrayforeach(this.logs(), function (log) {
                    if (log.id() >= 0 || log.id() <= 5000) {
                        filteredLogs.push(log);
                    }
                });
            }

    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I am hoping someone can shed some light on where I am going wrong with this as I am looking at learning knockout.js much more over the next few months.

Comment: In your `<select>` you are using the binding `selectedOptions` that is for multi select (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html).  If you only need one value, you need to change it to `value` (see examples here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).  :-)

Comment: Also, `self.resetFilter = function () { self.chosenFilter(null) },` should be set to `undefined`:  `self.chosenFilter(undefined)`.  It is the value that first gets the observable when you do `self.chosenFilter = ko.observable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your filteredLogs should be a computed field and depend on initial logs array and filter:

```
 this.filteredLogs = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!this.chosenFilter()) {
            return this.logs();
        }

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.logs(), function (logItem) {
            return log.id() >= 0 || log.id() <= 5000;
        });
    }, this);
```

When you mention some variables in computed variable body - your computed builds dependencies on those variables and when any of them changes - computed recalculates itselt by executing own body again.

Be carefull with pushing a lot of items in batch - because every push will trigger computed recalculation and can cause performance issues.

Also, in your html you should change binding to `foreach: filteredLogs`

Comment: Thanks - I understand your method of doing this and why it would work.  However when i try this in my project the original logs do not display to start with, and no filters are selected when code is first ran. @Olga Shumeliuk

Comment: @c_user Your javascript has some errors.  Here is a working fiddle with  Olga Shumeliuk solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/yb9e28p3/.

I changed the `||` to `&&` because you need both conditions to hold.  :-)